# Converting Repeated Names in Dataframe to Single Values

Tags: python

Looking for this:
Anthony now equals 1
John now equals 2 
Smith now equals 3 
and this goes on and on even if the name is repeated.. Looking for this
1
1
2
2
3
3

The code is fairly long but here is the spot I need to convert the names to numbers

LM = frame[['Name','COMMENT']]    -> Name is currently characters in a movie and I want to change it over to Numbers to be able to run a SVM Model through the Response Variable 'Name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to look at `pd.factorize` or convert name to pd.Categorical and use categorgy_codes.

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':np.random.choice(['John','Smith','Anthony'],10)})

df['Name_Code'] = pd.factorize(df.Name)[0] + 1

df
```

Output:

```
      Name  Name_Code
0  Anthony          1
1    Smith          2
2  Anthony          1
3  Anthony          1
4     John          3
5  Anthony          1
6  Anthony          1
7    Smith          2
8  Anthony          1
9    Smith          2
```

OR

```
df['Name_Cat_Code'] = pd.Categorical(df.Name).codes + 1
```

Output:

```
      Name  Name_Code  Name_Cat_Code
0  Anthony          1              1
1    Smith          2              3
2  Anthony          1              1
3  Anthony          1              1
4     John          3              2
5  Anthony          1              1
6  Anthony          1              1
7    Smith          2              3
8  Anthony          1              1
9    Smith          2              3
```

Comment: @AnthonyRichard if this answer helped you, I'd really appreciate if you would [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).  Thank you.